# Wordpress "Vote It Up" plugin help

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a dig like site with wordpress, TDO Mini forms and Vote it up where people who live in the city can log on, post their ideas of how to improve the city and have others vote.

on the home page there are 2 columns. right is the TDO submit form. left are the "Most Wanted" items. the posts with the highest rating. I've found an impressive lack of information on this plugin. im not great with php but i can make do most of the time.

I want to output the post title, post author, links for yes and no votes as well as have the titles in the left column list in most popular order. preferably id like the home pages to have only the top 5 or so highest rated posts.

I cant find any way to output that information as i need. I was really hoping there was a simple way to call the highest rated post titles in the loop for the main page but there doesnt seem to be a way. Bout the only thing i've found is the DisplayVotes tag which isnt incredibly helpful.

does anybody know how i can accomplish this, or can provide some expert advise? help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I was ready to download your plugin.  Too bad it is not done.